# Identity Server Get new token or populate claim without logout

Tags: c#, security, oauth, claims-based-identity, identityserver4

implicit grant flow:

Is there a way I can get new bearer token <strike>(and new refresh_token?)</strike> for specific scenario.

So I have some actions on app where its going to call api on the server which will need to populate new claims (and new bearer token as a result).

My question is how (or where) do I do this without user logging out?

Thanks,

EDIT:

As it turns out refresh tokens in implict flow is a bad idea.

Prob. another way to put the same question ...

In Identity Server 4 is there any where (a delegate, method call etc.) which can be used to add new claims to the existing token? So for e.g. If I have an endpoint https://myauthserver/changemypincode and from that endpoint I can call this (a delegate, method call etc.) to add new claims to the token (it could create new token as result but thats fine) and return to client?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but you can solve this by using the IdentityServerTools to generate a new token.

```
private async Task<string> CreatePaymentsTokenAsync()
{
    var tokenLifeTime = 3600;
    var scopes = new[] { CoinbaseAuthConsts.PaymentScope };
        // Use in-built Identity Server tools to issue JWT
    var token = await _identityServerTools.IssueClientJwtAsync(CoinbaseAuthConsts.AuthorityClientId, 
            tokenLifeTime, scopes, new[] { "YourApiName" });
    return token;
}
```